# Amazon Corretto 8 32 bits

Tags: java, windows, 32-bit, corretto

I'm current using Oracle JDK 8 32 bits to my application and I was wondering if there is any possibility to Amazon Corretto 8 be released on 32 bits version.

Comment: What platform are your running on?

Comment: Hi @YishaiGalatzer. I'm running over Microsoft Windows (win 7 and above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Released in 2019 ...

Past Update:

I filed [issue on GitHub/Corretto](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/22) to track this request. Once we have bits ready we will update both on GitHub and here

Comment: Already downloaded the version and currently using. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Corretto preview2 is now available and it includes a Windows 32 bits release on the [downloads page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html)